# trcsess utility problem

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle-12c

Can trcsess utility merge files pertaining to a user session scattered across different processes in a shared server configuration?

Is this tool have this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> #### TRCSESS
>
> TRCSESS is useful for consolidating the tracing of a particular session for performance or debugging purposes.

Yes, you can merge the scattered user session trace files using this tool and can get formatted out using TKPROF.

> #### TKPROF
>
> TKPROF can locate statements using the greatest resource. With baselines available, you can assess whether the resources used are reasonable given the work done.

Its usage and syntax are given in the following reference in details.

***Reference***:[Tracing Utilities](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_trace.htm#TGSQL95367)